# A chord of a parabola

Tags: analytic-geometry, quadratics, conic-sections

If a chord, which is not a tangent, of the parabola $y^2=16x$ has the equation $2x+y=p$, and midpoint $(h,k)$, then which of the following is (are) possible values of $p, h$ and $k$?
$A)\: p=-2, h=2, k=-4$;
$B)\: p=-1, h=1, k=-3$;
$C)\: p=2, h=3, k=-4$;
$D)\: p=5, h=4, k=-3$

If I do it by mid point of chord formula i.e. $S_1=T$ then I get $C)$ as answer, which is actually correct.

If I use the intersecting line concept i.e. $c \lt \frac am$ then I don't get any answer. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $2x=p-y,$ we obtain:
$$y^2=8(p-y)$$ or
$$y^2+8y-8p=0,$$ which gives $$y_1+y_2=-8$$ and $$k=\frac{y_1+y_2}{2}=-4.$$
If $p=-2$ we obtain:
$$y^2+8y+16=0$$ or
$$(y+4)^2=0,$$ which gives that $2x+y=p$ is a tangent to the parabola, which is impossible.

Can you end it now?

Comment: Hi, thanks. Since the line is an intersecting line, so, $c\lt \frac am$. Is that correct? So, $p\lt \frac{4}{-2}\implies p\lt -2$. So, no answer matches. Is this a wrong method?

Comment: @Ramit   But $p=2$ is valid. For this value $(3,-4)$ is a mid-point of the chord.

Comment: I am getting $p$ should be less than $-2$. As per that, no answer matches. Though, with other approaches, I am indeed getting $C)$ as the correct answer.

Comment: @Ramit For intersection we need $16+8p>0$, which gives $p>-2$ and $p=2$ is valid. Yes, the correct answer is $C)$.

Comment: Hi. If we have a line $y=mx+c$ and a parabola $y^2=4ax$ then can we say that for this line to intersect the parabola $c\lt \frac am$?

Comment: @Ramit  No! In our case $m<0$ and it should be $c>\frac{a}{m}.$

Comment: Thanks, got it now.